# slow insert into SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, xml-parsing

In my project I have 157 xml files, 5000 nodes each. The nodes contain some metadata anda full text of a press article. From each node I have to extract certain information and insert it into database.

The columns in my database are:
-AN number of an article (varchar(25))
-Full text of an article (varchar(max))

What I do now is to create a tuple of two elements for each node and then insert it to the database row by row.

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server='SERVER', user='USER', password='PASSWORD', database='DATABASE')
cursor = conn.cursor()
for tup in data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE VALUES (%s, %s)', (tup[0], tup[1]))

conn.commit()
```

It achieves the expected result but takes 20-30 minutes per file. I don't think writing 5000 rows into database should take that much.

I also tried using pandas Dataframe.to_sql but I think it doesn't permit MS SQL Server.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server 2014` try to use `Delayed Durability`: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/07/20/sql-server-delayed-durability-story-speed-autotests-11-2-5-minutes/ also please provide code where you parse your xml

Comment: 1. Is the database local or on a remote machine? if it is on a remote machine then your bottleneck might be the network and not the db. 2. There is no point in deconstructing the tuple and then creating a new one, you can simplify your code by doing `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE VALUES (%s, %s)', tup)` or `tup[:2]` in case `tup` has more than 2 elements.

Comment: @Devart: I use SQL Server 2012, I don't think parsing XML is the problem, it literally takes miliseconds;

Comment: @DeepSpace: It's on remote machine in my network. Good point with deconstructing the tuple. I'll see if it affects the performance.

Comment: @DeepSpace: passing the entire tuple hasn't improved the performance

Comment: @pawelty I didn't expect it to, the number 1 suspect is the network. I would also try committing every few iterations then all at once, but we can only guess from here... even pymssql's `executemany` does it your way: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/55e9e8ae86a6b69d89ed4ae9751b054c24d99ea6/src/pymssql.pyx#L471

Comment: Yeah executemany took the same time... What could potentially be a problem with the network?

Comment: I need to use VPN to connect to this server, can this be a problem?

Comment: I'm also running into the same issues. I've found this problem only with SQL Server, especially if the DB is hosted in a separate server. As for postgresql then inserting (in my case, more than 80000 records) doesn't take that long (less than 5 minutes).